# How to get, on client side, statusCode? javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

On server side I did redirect:

```
res.statusMessage = 'Attachment is encrypted'
return res.redirect("/printapprovals");
```

now I want check statusCode on the client side - I can see the status code on chrome tools:

> Request
>   URL:http://localhost:3000/downloadFile/e98b8560-2164-11e6-9940-adcca17ecd7b
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:302 Attachment is encrypted Remote
>   Address:127.0.0.1:3000

Also a good solution for me - if we get statusCode on the route... but how?

```
var testRoute = function (req, res) {  
  return res.render('print_page', { data: data })
}
```

Comment: What is your `client side`? Some kind of ajax? Or `require('request')`? May be `curl`?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's browser. If it's `XmlHttpRequest` - it process redirects transparently, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode); // <======= Here's the status code
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: absolutely false, the guy wants to read the status code client side, your answer is about server side